# phpmyadmin is listing my server version and client version as being different

Tags: linux-mint, apt, mysql

In a continuation of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55670/13026), I have purged the 5.1 client via `sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.1`.  I have reinstalled the 5.5 client - `sudo apt-get --reinstall install mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5`.  I've also restarted apache and MySQL.  Despite that, phpmyadmin still lists the client as being 5.1.  Any ideas how to fix it?

EDIT:

It tells me that `mysql-client-5.1` is not installed.  `mysql --version` returns:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

Comment: When you use `apt-get purge` you only listed `client-core` did you do `apt-get purge mysql-client-5.1` as well? What is the output of `mysql --verison`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research shows that the 'client version' listed by phpmyadmin is the version of the PHP MySQL module I have installed, and has nothing to do with the actual MySQL client.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you stated, I ran into that problem a year ago, just to eventually discover that phpmyadmin reports the version of the mysqli module it uses to connect to the actual mysql server.